# iOS save all files from remote directory at local document directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am properly sending a nsurlrequest to download a known path file and then save it to document directory. However, now I need to download all files that a remote directory contains. I know path for directory but not which files are inside. How to list that files in order to build paths to download it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately unless you parsed a index file containing a list of the files, this is not possible as the HTTP protocol does not support directory listing. You would have to use an FTP server instead

Comment: Bad news but good to know, then I will create xml file at same folder for listing. Thank you.